# how to map object that extends collections?

Tags: graphql-java, graphql-spring-boot

I'm using graphql-java. My problem is: I have an object that extends LinkedHashMap and I do not know how to map it to my schema. Can someone help me?

[I'm using graphql-java-tools](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/)

and [graphql-spring-boot](https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/spring-boot/)

CODE:

```
public class XPTO extends LinkedHashMap<String, String>  {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class XPTO {\n");
    sb.append("    ").append(toIndentedString(super.toString())).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

Graphql schema:

```
type XPTO {
    key: String
    value: String
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some source code and how do you want to map you Map to an object.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli 
code is already available

Comment: I would suggest not to extend from LinkedHashMap. Because XPTO looks like a MapEntry. So you should create another class that can deal with MapEntries.

Comment: Okay. I'll consider this change. But the doubt still persists. How would I map to my schema